# institution with a plural verb in British English

Tags: british-english, subject-verb-agreement, dialect

I'm wondering whether it's common for a subject referring to a business to go with a plural verb in British English.

For example, would it be natural to say "QuickStart Inc. **are** planning to expand into Europe"?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: This question has been asked a gazillion times here on ELL. For example https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/151339/can-the-khmer-rouge-be-a-singular-noun/151340#151340

Comment: but a company name may be different from a collective noun like "committee."

Comment: The company question has been asked ten gazillion times.

Comment: Really? I can only find posts related to pronoun choice, not subject-verb agreement involving names of organizations.